# Projeto JSP Eclipse - Linkando página de estilo CSS

Tags: css, jsp, servlet

como linkar de forma correta minhas folhas de estilo no meu projeto JSP Servlet? Segue abaixo a estrutura do meu projeto.
Também não sei se a hierarquiaesta correta. Me ajudem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
Já tentei ../webapp/style/estilo.css e nada. Tentei modificar e colocar a folha de estilo na pasta webapp e linkar:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" >
```

Mas não dá, e tipo na página fica só uma borda, não puxa tudo...

Página INICIO.JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>
<%@ page import="br.edu.unilasalle.model.*" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link href="style/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="fundo">
    <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
    <h3>Opções</h3>
    <a href='CadastroUsuario.jsp'>Cadastro de Usuário</a><br>
    <a href='CadastroBancos.jsp'>Cadastro de Bancos</a><br>
    <a href='CadastroCategorias.jsp'>Cadastro de Categorias</a>

<%
    if(request.getSession(true).getAttribute("usuario")!=null){

    Usuario usuario=        
   (Usuario)request.getSession(true).getAttribute("usuario");
%>
<p>
    Usuário: <%=usuario.getId()%>. <%=usuario.getNomeCompleto() %>   <a     
    href="LogoutController">Sair</a>
</p>

<%} %>
</body>
</html>
```

Página de estilo.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body{
    background: rgba(0,77,153,0.6);
    border: 4px solid #8080c0;
    margin: 200px 500px 0px 500px;
    border-radius: 125px;
}

div {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

#acesso{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: blue;
}

.fundo{
    background: url('../WebContent/img/wallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que li em seu comentario voce diz que a unica propriedade que funciona é " Border: 4px" .

Então isso quer dizer que você esta chamando a folha de estilo de forma correta!!!

O problema é provalvemente o estilo ou a pagina....
Apague tudo da sua folha de estilo e mude so a cor de fundo da pagina para fazer um teste.

Caso de certo vá adicionando um a um  os estilos na sua folha de estilo e em sua pgina confera se eles estao funcionando um a um .

Onde você chama a div , o id `#acesso` ?

Você tem que chamar eles na pagina jsp!!!
Se não chamar não funciona!!

Voce apenas chamou aqui nesse trecho do seu codgo `<body class="fundo">`
tem que fazer o mesmo para os demais propriedades do seu css.

```
<body class="fundo">
    <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
    <h3>Opções</h3>
<div>
    <a href='CadastroUsuario.jsp'>Cadastro de Usuário</a><br>
    <a href='CadastroBancos.jsp'>Cadastro de Bancos</a><br>
    <a href='CadastroCategorias.jsp'>Cadastro de Categorias</a>
</div>
<p id="acesso"> Isso é uma id</p>
<%
    if(request.getSession(true).getAttribute("usuario")!=null){

    Usuario usuario=        
   (Usuario)request.getSession(true).getAttribute("usuario");
%>
<p>
    Usuário: <%=usuario.getId()%>. <%=usuario.getNomeCompleto() %>   <a     
    href="LogoutController">Sair</a>
</p>

<%} %>
</body>
```

A forma que eu usei a div e o id acima é só um exemplo, não quer dizer que tem de serem usados  exatamente nesses lugares , voce esta livre para usar onde quiser..

Quanto a forma de chamar o link,que não é o problema,  tente assim:

```
<link href="style/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

ou

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/estilo.css" />
```

No primeiro caso acima voce pode adicionar `../` ou remover para achar a profundidade onde esta  a sua pagina de estilo.
Por exemplo :

```
 <link href="../style/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="../../style/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
```

Comment: Não funciona. Abre a página e a unica propriedade da folha de estilo que funciona é a Border: 4px; Na folha tem algumas propriedades e inspecionando o código, elas ficam riscadas... Por que?

Comment: Removi todos comentários

Comment: Bah... pior que funcionou! Que descuido meu e nem me dei conta!

Comment: Muito bem ! Da proxima vicê ja sabe!! Valeu!!!